# MVC -- creating Controller Action CreateNewEmployee in Northwind DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to create a new Employee in MVC. 
Controller :

```
HireEmployeeBL.EmployeeBL employeeBl = new HireEmployeeBL.EmployeeBL();

    public ActionResult HireNew(int id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HireNew(int id, Employee employee)
{
    employee.ReportsTo = new Manager { EmployeeID = id };
    employeeBl.AddEmployee(employee);
    return RedirectToAction("Subordinates");
    //return View();
}
```

Server Error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult HireNew(Int32)' in
>   'MvcEmployee.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Are you passing both an id of type `int` and employee of type `Employee` to your controller action?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: yes im passing both of them to controller Action

Comment: What does your view / form look like? Btw, you're not passing them both... I'm not trying to be rude, but the fact is, if you were passing an 'id' parameter, your wouldn't be getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            try
            {
                NorthwindEntities northwindEntities = new NorthwindEntities();
                northwindEntities.Employees.Add(employee);
                northwindEntities.SaveChanges(); 

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: i forgotten to add " HireEmployeeBL.EmployeeBL employeeBl = new HireEmployeeBL.EmployeeBL();" i use employeeBl instead of NorthwindEntities

Comment: and you must call - northwindEntities.SaveChanges(); - for actually saving it in the database.

Comment: And really you should extract this to the model, and keep logic inside controllers as thin as possible.